# Detail band with page break

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I have a report that contains a page break in the detail section .
in the first part of the detail section (before the page break) i have put a subreport containing an image.

When running the report i have two pages (as expected ) but the image is displayed in both pages.Is there a tip to display my image in the first page only?

To test i moved it after the page break and it worked correctly (displayed the image in the second page only). Why the first method is not working on the first page only?

Comment: You should post the small sample (*jrxml*) to reproduce the problem. The image is also will be helpful to understand the case

Comment: Hello , thanks for your response Alex !  I resolved this issue by putting the subreport in the "column footer" band , and in the "Print when expression" of the subreport i used this expression to display it in the first pages only : new Boolean(($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue()%2)!=0 ) .I hope this can help someone :)

Comment: You can post solution as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by putting the subreport in the *Column Footer* band, and in the "Print when expression" of the subreport I used this expression to display it in the first pages only:

```
new Boolean($V{PAGE_NUMBER}.intValue() % 2 != 0)
```

Comment: `I used this expression to display it in the first pages only` - It will be work not for only first page :)

Comment: first pages* , cause my report must display two pages for each row in the report entity (results of the query ) and i needed the image in the each first page of the two pages :)